# Is DXA 2.2 (Java) compatible with Sites 9.5?

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, model-service, sites-9.5

After installing the Model Service from DXA 2.2 (Java) to Tridion Sites 9.5, the service starts successfully.

However when requesting the page using Postman the below stacktrace is seen

```
{
"timestamp": [
    "String",
    "2020-09-22T17:21:22.317+0000"
],
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProviderException",
"message": "Couldn't deserialize DD4T content for request PageRequestDto(publicationId=8, pageId=0, path=/index.html, uriType=tcm, includePages=INCLUDE, contentType=MODEL, dataModelType=R2, expansionDepth=100, depthCounter=DepthCounter(counter=100, unlimited=false))",
"path": "/PageModel/tcm/8/index.html"}
```

Additional details:

- Page and component templates were built using TBBs from DXA R2 model folder.
- OpenJDK 64-bit 11.0.8+10 is JVM
- Documentation link for DXA 2.2 data model below.  Note that 9.5 is not mentioned in the compatibility matrix as DXA 2.2 was released before 9.5
  https://docs.sdl.com/784837/746726/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/installing-------------dxa-data-model-support

Is DXA 2.2 (Java) compatible with Sites 9.5?

Comment: Did you register the model service as part of discovery or did you auto register and have you published everything can you check the services logs may be will get more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your questioon - Yes it's supported in sites 9.5, I did a test with sites 9.5 OOTB DXA 2.2 .NET and DXA 2.2.5 Java both working fine in sites 9.5.

**Note:**

DXA 2.2 in sites 9.0+ not required modelservice you can use DXA model extention.
In your case I would expect you need to upload this DXA Model extention in add-on service or load this extention in content service if you are not using add-on service, this extention file can be found in the installation media on this folder path **\Content Delivery\roles\content\add-ons\udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.5.0-1074-core.zip**

DXA 2.2 Java OOTB default it will use GraphQLContentProvider, In case if you want to use ContentProvider with Modelservice.

then Update the **dxa.properties** file to use the CIL-based providers rather than the default GraphQL providers (needed for SDL Tridion Sites 9 and later).

- Open the web application's **dxa.properties** file for editing.
- Find the property **spring.profiles.active**.
- Add **cil.providers.active** as a value of the property.

I hope it helps